# Strange problems about multidex, encryption unsuccessful

Tags: android, android-multidex

I suddenly have some very strange problems with my app:
After a minor change to my code (which I quoted /* */ after first problem, so I don't think it comes from here), I have an error about multiDex:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
> android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path:
> DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/.........-i-_Gfmdwe7_cZrleQ2mI9w==/base.apk", zip file
> "/data/app/com....

I checked that everything MultiDex needs was there: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Then I cleaned project, rebuild, closed Android Studio, reopen, and ran project on AVD (Nexus 5 API26 x86) and I have a new error: "Encryption unsuccessful... reset phone...)

I wiped data with AVD Manager, since then I have the same error as above, the Multidex thing. I really don't see why...

Answer (score 0):

I too had problem with multidex, and solved it by adding dependency to gradle:app module

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and in  manifest  application tag ,add

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

These changes helped me to solve my issue with multidex.

Class DexFile is deprecated in api level 26. You have to use PathClassLoader instead.
https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/PathClassLoader.html

Comment: I added these already. Problem occured suddenly. My version is multidex:1.0.2

Comment: Error log says: "No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.myproject-i-_Gfmdwe7_cZrleQ2mI9w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk"..
Android studio version : 3.0.1 / API 26 / 
From Manifest : android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
From build.gradle : implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
with google serrvices and firebase 11.6.2
And override fun attachBaseContext(context: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    } in my activity

Comment: Did you add "multiDexEnabled true" in default config?

Comment: try with disabling Dex preopt

Comment: I had multiDexEnabled true. I don't know how to disable this Dex Preopt. I'm confused as I really don't understand why suddenly I have this error after modifying a minor thing with a Dialog, wich since I changed back. This "Encryption unsuccessful" on the emulator is not understandable for me.. it looks like a virus or I dont know.. I will try to uninstall/reinstall android studio. Could it have something to do with Firestore/Firebase wich I use ?

Comment: Class DexFile is deprecated in api level 26. You have to use PathClassLoader instead.

Answer (score 0):

After trying 10k things, I noticed that my com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha04' was ready to update.
So I changed alpha04 to alpha05 in Project Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha05'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
```

And it works. But why would it be soooooo unstable ?

> Android Studio 3.0.1 Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 Kotlin v. 1.2.0
>
> implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2' implementation
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'  implementation
>   'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'